# Arduino com contador

Tags: c, algoritmo, arduino

Não consigo entender o que tem de errado nesse código, era para eu apertar *s1* uma vez e *m1* ficar ligado porém ele desliga depois de um tempo. O programa também não conta como deveria.

A questão é essa:
No sistema abaixo quando uma peça é colocada na posição dada pelo sensor *s1* o motor *m1* é ligado, levando a peça até o sensor *s2* e caindo na caixa de saída. Sabe-se que a caixa suporta até 20 peças. Implemente um contador `(cont)` para que e somente quando 20 peças caírem na caixa o motor *m1* é desligado e a lâmpada *l1* é ligada, alertando ao operador da necessidade de trocar a caixa. Implemente um algoritmo que atenda o solicitado.

```
const int s1 = 6;

const int s2 = 7;

const int m1 = 8;

const int l1 = 11;

int cont = 0;

void setup() {

// put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(s1, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(s2, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(l1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(m1, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

   void loop(){

  while(digitalRead(s1) == HIGH){

    Serial.print("Valor de S1 = ");

    Serial.println(s1);

 }

  digitalWrite(m1, HIGH);

  if((digitalRead (s2) == LOW) && (cont < 20)){

    cont ++;

    Serial.print("número de vezes em que o botão foi pressionado:");

    Serial.println(cont);

    }

  else{

  digitalWrite (m1, LOW);

digitalWrite (l1, HIGH);

 delay(5000); //tempo para o LED permanecer acesso

 digitalWrite (l1, LOW);

 }

 }
```

Comment: Cara, identa o código, e tem uma chave sobrando no final, e o que você quer fazer está fora do loop(), isso vai causar que o que esta fora do loop() executar apenas uma vez.

Comment: Lembre-se que o que está em setup() é executado apenas uma vez, o que está em loop() ficará "eternamente" executando

Comment: Como faço para identar o código, qual chave que está sobrando?

Comment: Ué mais está dentro do loop()

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui. Esse foi o código que eu usei:
 const int s1 = 6;

const int s2 = 7;

const int m1 = 8;

const int l1 = 11;

int cont = 0;

void setup() {

// put your setup code here, to run once:

pinMode(s1, INPUT_PULLUP);

pinMode(s2, INPUT_PULLUP);

pinMode(l1, OUTPUT);

pinMode(m1, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(9600);

while(digitalRead(s1) == HIGH){

```
Serial.print("Valor de S1 = ");

Serial.println(s1);
```

}

```
digitalWrite(m1, HIGH);
```

}

void loop(){

```
if((digitalRead (s2) == LOW) && (cont < 20)){

cont ++;

Serial.print("número de vezes em que o botão foi pressionado:");

Serial.println(cont);

}

 else if((digitalRead (s2) == HIGH) && (cont >= 20)){

  digitalWrite (m1, LOW);

  digitalWrite (l1, HIGH);

  delay(5000); //tempo para o LED permanecer acesso

  digitalWrite (l1, LOW);

 }
```

}